# SQLite error running sql file

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am getting a syntax error (near as) on line 22 which is

```
 CREATE VIEW myDat 
 AS
     SELECT count(*) AS count
     FROM disco l
     GROUP BY l.no;

22   SELECT * as no
     FROM myDat
     WHERE count > (SELECT avg(count) FROM myDat);
```

I can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong. I am assuming its the nested `SELECT` statement in the last line? I looked at the SQLite documentation and it seems be correct. But any other reason for errors?

Comment: You can not alias *. * indicates all columns.

Comment: What is the error message, and what is*all* the code?

Answer (score 2):

Change query to remove alias or set alias as below:

```
SELECT count as no
FROM myDat
WHERE count > (SELECT avg(count) FROM myDat);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't alias asterisk. You must remove alias, or replace asterisk by the column name `count`.